# Restoring backup from another installation and myy Encryption Password for Dejadup does not work. Why, and what do I do?

Tags: password, backup, security, encryption, deja-dup

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu. I was running Ubuntu MATE and decided to scale down to a stripped down version. I backed up all of my files to an external HDD and took a picture of my passphrase so I could make absolutely sure that there was no error in copying.
I installed Ubuntu and set it to encrypt my data, as before and took another picture of the passphrase provided during installation.

I went to restore the backup from the erased installation and when I input the passphrase it was not accepted. I tried both numerous times to make sure I was not making an error in transcription and that I was not just confused and using the wrong one.

Now my backed up data is inaccessible and I have lost all faith in Dejadup. What is the point of backing up your data if you have no access to it? What is the point of encrypting data if the passphrase is not going to work? What do I do now, just delete the backup and lose the past two months of work?

Comment: It might just be the way this is written, but I am confused, are you talking about your whole disk encryption passphrase or your deja-dup passphrase? Or both?  Are you having trouble mounting and decrypting your encrypted backup or with your deja-dup password?  At one point you say "I installed Ubuntu and set it to encrypt my data" but in the title you say "my encryption password for dejadup".

Comment: The only time I ever chose to encrypt anything was during installation of the OS. I was prompted for the password when attempting to restore my backup.